# Encapsulate global config variables as static?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, static

I have several variables that are global and mainly do not change.
Sometimes (every few month) I though want to change them.

They are saved in the DB.

Problem is: if I change the static vars, other services still use the old values.
What am I doing wrong?

```
class Config {
    public static Default DEFAULTS = new Default();
    //several other static defaults 

    public static in DIGIT = DEFAULTS.getDigit();
}


class Default() {
    private int digit = 0;
    //get+set
}

class Service() {
    updateDefaults() {
        Config.DEFAULTS.setDigit(2);
        dao.update(Config.DEFAULTS);
    }
}
```

Problem: other services that use `Config.DIGIT;` still use the old default value of `digit = 0`.

Comment: He has already deleted his nonsensicial comment (which just shows off that he didn't understand at all how `static` works). I'll delete my comment as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are updating the value of digits in the DEFAULTS instance of Default.  However the value for Config.DIGITS is already set and not reset, i.e. the assignment of DIGITS does not get updated because you change the value of DEFAULTS.digit.

Additionally, I assume there are some typos in this code, as Config.DEFAULTS is private here can not be updated directly.

Answer (score 1):

The value of `Config.DIGIT` is set once to `0`, and never changed.

You can either:

- update the value of `Config.DIGIT` in `Service.updateDefaults()`
- add a getter in the `Config` class to retrieve the value of `DEFAULTS.getDigit()`